# Count the number of non-zero columns in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix `mat`. Some of the columns of `mat` are all zeros while some of the columns are non-zero. How can I count the columns which are non-zero?

```r
mat<-matrix(rep(0,2*5),ncol=2)
mat[,1]=c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

The desired result is `1`.

Comment: Try `sum(colSums(mat == 0) != 0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the columns that have non-zero elements, meaning they may have zeros but not all the rows are zeros then the following works:

```r
mat<-matrix(rep(0,2*5),ncol=2)
mat[,1]=c(1,2,3,4,5)

sum(colSums(mat!=0)!=0)
#> [1] 1
```

But if you want to find the column which have no zeros, look below. I am making an example to illustrate that better:

```r
mat2<-matrix(rep(0,4*5),ncol=4)
mat2[,1]=c(0,2,3,4,5)
mat2[,2]=c(1,2,3,4,5)
mat2[,3]=c(0,0,0,-1,1)

sum(colSums(mat2!=0)!=0) #count of non-zero columns
#> [1] 3

sum(colSums(mat2!=0)==nrow(mat2)) #count of columns with no zeros
#> [1] 1
```

If you want to find out which columns are non-zero then use `which` instead of `sum`:

```r
which(colSums(mat2!=0)!=0) #non-zero columns
#> [1] 1 2 3


which(colSums(mat2!=0)==nrow(mat2)) #columns with no zeros
#> [1] 2
```

Comment: @M-M could you also show how to identify which columns are the "non-zero columns?" i.e. columns 1, 2, and 3

Comment: @adm instead of `sum()` use `which()`. e.g. ```which(colSums(mat!=0)!=0)```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` column-wise and count number of columns which have `any` non-zero value

```
sum(apply(mat != 0, 2, any))
#[1] 1
```

Or if you want columns with `all` non-zero values

```
sum(apply(mat != 0, 2, all))
```

Comment: Somebody posted using `max` with `apply` and deleted their answer, since it wasn't working with all negative columns. I am just leaving this comment here since it is more like your solutions: `sum(apply(mat, 2, function(y) max(abs(y)))!=0)`